# Login +Thymeleaf+ Spring5+Security+ JWT+

Tags: login, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, thymeleaf

estoy teniendo problemas en un asunto de loguin y quisiera saber si me podrian dar algun consejo, bien mi proyecto posee un sistema de loguin en Spring5 con Spring security e implemento autenticacion con JWT, adna todo perfecto, con postman me autentico y recivo el token,  ahora mi problema es usar eso en una view, lo mas normal en un html de thymeleaf en el mismo proyecto de spring, no tengo idea de como enviar un formulario a la ruta de autenticacion y de como interceptar el token. Si envio el formulario de la manera normal resivo un json en la vista con los datos de la respuesta "un mensaje y el token" pero la idea no es resivir el json en la vista, sino interceptar el valor del token, guardarlo en session o en cooki y ser redireccionado a otra vista despues del loguin. Hace varios dias vengo investigando como usar jquery para realizar eso, pero todos mis metodos son infructuosos, cualquier ayuda seria muy agradecida, les dejo un link para que descarguen el proyecto https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmN81S-9jmjeh9YV38eaXD-I8wNFSQ

Comment: Por favor agrega a la preguna la configuración de Srping Security incluyendo beans que estés instanciando para reemplazar los defaults y que otros módulos de spring estás usando. En la pregunta decís que devuelve un json. El login lo estás haciendoe desde con un request desde el front del navegador o con xhr (Ajax)?

Comment: Ya logre resolver esta hace un par de horas, utilize el siguiente scrip para recivir el token del login:  function enviar(){
 $.ajax( {
  type: "POST",
  url: "/api/login",
  data: { "username": "admin", "password": "123" }
 } )
  .done( function( msg ) {
   window.token=msg;
   window.location.href="/listar"; 
   console.log( "Toma tu token de mierda: " + window.token.token );

 } );
 }

Comment: Ahora lo que quisiera saber es como guardar el token en una variable global en el cliente, para asi poder guardar el token en esa variable y poder utilizarlo en los headers de mis request.

Comment: Me parece que tendrías abrir una pregunta aparte para esto. En todo caso esto nuevo que has agregado, por lo menos,  debería estar dentro de la pregunta y no como comentario. Lo podés agregar editando la pregunta. En cuanto a donde guardar el token, tenés el "session storage" en el navegador. Habiendo dicho esto, también tenés la opción de manejar la sesión con cookies y ahorrarte este tema.

Comment: Muchas gracias juan, lo intentare y en caso de no poder modificare el titulo para pedir ayuda sobre los session storaga  o las cookies.